# Web browsers loading ttf file instead of woff file

Tags: cross-browser, font-face, truetype, woff

I included a True Type Font in the @font-face CSS setting so that Android browsers can display a certain web font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GNU FreeMono';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('fonts/GNU_FreeFont/FreeMono.woff') format('woff');
  src: url('fonts/GNU_FreeFont/FreeMono.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

However, this inclusion causes other browsers (Google Chrome, Firefox, etc) to download the `.ttf` file instead of the compressed `.woff` file. Reversing the order of `src` will cause Android browsers to be unable to display the web font. This seems to defeat the purpose of having the `.woff` file.

Is there a way for CSS to make non-Android browsers use the `.woff` file and support Android's use of `.ttf` at the same time?

Comment: Do you have android 4.4 browser? http://caniuse.com/woff  , http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff

Comment: @SergieMonks, I ask this question precisely because I need to support Android users without the latest 4.4 browser :)